# How co call methods of EAGLView from ES1Renderer?

Tags: objective-c, delegates, protocols, eaglview

Using the standard OpenGL ES iPad pattern we get such 'structure'. I've read some about delegating, protocols, but still got no direct answer for this particular purpose. Please enlighten me.

Why would I need this? Well all the action goes on in ES1Renderer and I want to `[EAGLView setUserInteractionEnabled:true];` for example, which gives me:

> 'EAGLView' may not respond to
>   '+setUserInteractionEnabled:'

Answer (score 0):

You're sending a message to a class, not an instance. You'd need an object of type `EAGLview` to send the `setUserInteractionEnabled:` message to.

Like:

```
EAGLView *myView;
[myView setUserInteractionEnabled:true];
```